# How to make a terminal window always float on top?

Tags: windows

I see tons of people who have asked this question in the past, and the answer is always the same.. "Use Afloat".  But since Afloat hasn't been updated in ages, and has only support for certain applications (and questionable support at that), I'm afraid that it is not an acceptable solution.

I want to be able to make an arbitrary window - in this case a terminal window - float on top of all other windows.  Please note that this is NOT the same as keeping it on "all desktops" (I'm already doing that), as the window will still pop behind other windows on the other desktops.

How can I, Using OSX Lion circa December of 2012, keep a specific Terminal window on top of all other windows, of all other applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TotalTerminal might be a better option. TotalTerminal has a visor mode that allows it to stay on top of all the other windows. You can choose to place it anywhere on the desktop, of course, and choose to have it slide out from one of those positions when you use CTRL-~ key combo or anything else you’ve set up. Plus it’s free.

Comment: Holy crap this is awesome.  How did I not know about this seeing as I already use TotalFinder???  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well since I was striking out otherwise, I decided to try Afloat anyway.  Discovered in their knowledgebase that it WAS updated to work with Lion 10.7.  It still doesn't support all apps, but it does work with Terminal, which is all I was after so I'm happy.  =)

Comment: Footnote - after a week of using Afloat, I removed it.  It caused massive instabilities and constant crashes in my system, and the SIMBL plugin library it installs/uses was always the culprit.  If anyone knows of another way to achieve the effect posted in the question, I would very much like to hear it!

Comment: Try using EasySIMBL instead.... I'm pleased with it.. Just installed Afloat, will see if it works ok via EasySIMBL: http://cl.ly/image/15233f0w2T3H